# Maven tomcat6 plugin to copy resources/properties file to custom path

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I've a tricky configuration, I've properties files which are currently inside my webapps folder I would like to copy these configuration out of my webapps folder say `c:\kp\conf` or `${catalina.home}/conf`.

I could achieve this configuration by adding the above location as classpath by appending property `common.loader` in `catalina.properties` file.

Now the real problem.

I'm using the tomcat6 plugin to deploy/redeploy my war/applications to tomcat 6 server. How do I configure my tomcat6 plugin to copy the resources to the above mentioned location? I do not want to copy it manually.

I checked with maven copy-resources plugin it will copy the resources to the local machine were the you are running the maven build but not to the server location

Can somebody suggest me how to use the tomcat6 plugin or any alternative plugin which will copy the to the location when deploying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always the swiss army knife [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). Suppose you have a shell script which does the copying for you, you could add something like this to you POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>bash</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${basedir}/scripts/copy-your-files.sh</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks for that. Btw can I run the java code instead of bash/script. So that it will be environment independent(using java advantage, I've development environment in windows and production in linux

Comment: Oops... sorry, went through documentation of plugin, I can happily use java code. Thanks for quick solution